# Make sure there is no overlapping

Tags: mysql, sql

I am trying to make a SQL statement for a project I am working on. It should return all `vehicleId` that are the right size vehicle and are not already scheduled at that date in the rentals table.

**Schema (of 2 tables involved)**

```
Vehicles(vehicleId, size)
Rental(rentId, customerId, vehicleId, startdate, enddate, cost)

SELECT vehicles.vehicleId 
FROM vehicles 
WHERE vehicles.size= "van" 
AND vehicles.vehicleId <> 
(SELECT rental.vehicleId 
 FROM rental 
WHERE (rental.startdate BETWEEN '2016-04-27' AND '2016-04-30')  
OR (rental.enddate BETWEEN  '2016-04-27'  AND '2016-04-30' ))
```

The first part of the statement, before the AND, returns all the vehicleid with size van and the second part, after the AND, should remove any vehicleid that is scheduled in the time frame by checking if either the startdate or enddate overlap. But the second part is not working like that and when run the whole thing returns nothing.

What is wrong with the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem may be the quotes in the original query and the use of `<>` instead of `NOT IN`.  But, more importantly, the logic for overlaps is wrong.  I think you want:

```
SELECT v.vehicleId 
FROM vehicles v
WHERE v.size = 'van' AND
      v.vehicleId NOT IN (SELECT r.vehicleId 
                          FROM rental r 
                          WHERE r.startdate <= '2016-04-30' AND
                                r.enddate >= '2016-04-27'
                         );
```

As a trivial example, a rental from '2016-04-01' to '2016-05-01' would not be tagged correctly by your logic.

The correct logic for overlapping time periods is that one period starts before the other ends and the first ends after the other starts.

Answer (score 1):

You didn't quote your dates, so they're not dates - they're math expressions:

```
 rental.enddate BETWEEN 2016-04-27 AND 2016-04-30
```

executes as if it was "2016 minus 4 minus 27":

```
 rental.enddate BETWEEN 1985 AND 1982
```

They should all be quoted:

```
 rental.enddate BETWEEN '2016-04-27' AND '2016-04-30'
```

Comment: added quotes in but the statement still returns nothing. (edited above to reflect change)

Comment: you also probably want `not in` instead of `<>`, if the subquery can return multiple rows of data.

Comment: NOT IN was what I needed. Thanks I have been stuck on this for longer than I would care to admit.

Comment: you should have gotten a warning/error about the `<>` thing. better check your error handling.